# What's the state of hybrid graphics in 2018?

Tags: drivers, nvidia, graphics, nvidia-optimus, nvidia-prime

I have a laptop with both Intel and Nvidia graphics, running Ubuntu 18.04. I've installed and selected the proprietary Nvidia drivers via the *Software & Updates* GUI (the card is a GTX 1050, which Nouveau doesn't seem to support at all), and my system is happily running with the discrete GPU rendering everything, but obviously that's not exactly optimal in terms of battery life.

I've spent several hours trying to work out what I need to do to get hybrid graphics set up (i.e. the Intel iGPU drawing the desktop, but the Nvidia dGPU drawing GPU-intensive applications like games), but it seems like all the information I find is out-of-date or contradictory.

Is there an easy and supported way, in 2018, to use hybrid graphics on Linux?

Comment: With nVidia you use `prime-select intel` or `prime-select nvidia` and then you reboot. It's been this way for a long time and is not likely to change in 2018.

Comment: Seems like what you're looking for is Bumblebee. It allows you to run on the integrated intel graphics by default and just turn on and use the nvidia card for specific applications. Note however that the performance of Bumblebee is significantly lower than directly using the nvidia card only, and it only pays off for stuff that requires complex rendering. I managed to get it to work on my machine with the latest nvidia drivers from the `graphics-drivers/ppa` PPA and `bumblebee-nvidia` and `primus` from the `bumblebee/testing` PPA. It did require some additional configuration to work though.